# How to create Gcp Memory-store using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, automation, devops

I am trying to automate gcp memory store creation but didn't find a way to create it using python. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Python Client for Google Cloud Memorystore for Redis API**](https://googleapis.dev/python/redis/latest/index.html) in order to create it.

You can use the [**create_instance**](https://googleapis.dev/python/redis/latest/redis_v1/services.html) method of the Python Client Library which creates a Redis instance based on the specified tier and memory size

```
async create_instance(request: google.cloud.redis_v1.types.cloud_redis.CreateInstanceRequest = None, *,
 parent: str = None, instance_id: str = None, instance: google.cloud.redis_v1.types.cloud_redis.Instance = None, retry: 
google.api_core.retry.Retry = <object object>, timeout: float = None, metadata: Sequence[Tuple[str, str]] = ())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    from google.cloud import redis_v1beta1
    from google.cloud.redis_v1beta1 import enums
    client = redis_v1beta1.CloudRedisClient()
    parent = client.location_path('<project>', '<location>')
    
    instance_id = 'test-instancee'
    tier = enums.Instance.Tier.BASIC
    memory_size_gb = 1
    instance = {'tier': tier, 'memory_size_gb': memory_size_gb}
    response = client.create_instance(parent, instance_id, instance)
    def callback(operation_future):
        # Handle result.
        result = operation_future.result()
    response.add_done_callback(callback)
    # Handle metadata.
    # metadata = response.metadata()
    print "Created"
```

This Code will work fine but for python2, Is there any way to use it in python3 please mention.

Comment: Python2 is deprecated now, and it is also mentioned at the top in the [Python Client for Google Memorystore for Redis API](https://googleapis.dev/python/redis/latest/index.html), ```As of January 1, 2020 this library no longer supports Python 2 on the latest released version. Library versions released prior to that date will continue to be available. For more information please visit Python 2 support on Google Cloud```. And we can also see that the Python Client API is for Python3.6, 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: the snippet I added, it is not working with python3 , but it is working in python2. Please tell me what I am missing here.